# Por que minha condição nunca é true?

Tags: javascript, html, array, if, for

Por que o meu código não funciona? to testando uns códigos aqui , como um de advinhação, to tentando ver se funciona se adicionar numeros aleatórios em um array. mas a minha condição não funciona , nenhum objeto do array que coloco com input não dá certo. sei que devia ter algo melhor que prompt como input, mas fiz algo rápido só pra testar mesmo.

```
<script>


var numerosAleatorio = [];
for(var i =0; i < 10; i++){
    numerosAleatorio.push(Math.round(Math.random() * 100));
}

var index = 0;

while (index < 3) {
    var chute = prompt("advinhe um número");
    if (chute == numerosAleatorio) {
        alert("você acertou");
        break;
    } 
    index++;
}

console.log(numerosAleatorio);
```

[image: código]

Comment: Não sou o melhor em javascript, mas me parece que a saída do prompt é uma string, e o número não

Comment: Além do que foi reportado, você está comparando um array com o valor de uma variável. O que espera dessa comparação? Na verdade o que deveria fazer é iterar o array e comparar os itens do array com o valor lido na variável `chute`.

Comment: Desculpe, faz pouco tempo que comecei a programar

Comment: Utilizar um _for_ seria a forma mais didática de resolver o problema, mas você também pode utilizar o método _incldes_. Ao invés de `chute == numerosAleatorio` faça `numerosAleatorio.includes(Number(chute))`

Comment: Vlw Andre, testei aqui e funcionou

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você não está chamando o elemento na condição, então, use um dos diversos modos de percorrer os elementos do array na condicional. Um exemplo de resolução:

```
while (index < 3) {
var chute = prompt("advinhe um número");

//método find() para buscar no array o chute
if (numerosAleatorio.find(x => x == chute)) {
    alert("você acertou");
    break;
} 
index++;
```

}